# ExtractText : Split Flowfile into multiple copies based on dynamic attribute generated from each regex match?

Tags: apache-nifi

Is there a way to split incoming flowfile into multiple flowfiles (each carrying their parent attributes) for each matching regex captures?

Example:
Incoming flowfile contains below data:

```
Datafeed-Manifest-Version: 1.0
Lookup-Files: 1
Data-Files: 5
Total-Records: 2848792

Lookup-File: inventory-030000-lookup_data.tar.gz
MD5-Digest: fb7b275e624fb36f19eeedcdfa1aab09
File-Size: 37648783

Data-File: 01-inventory_20230110-030000.tsv.gz
MD5-Digest: 46b54b81c7103b45cbc8ab90b6119605
File-Size: 84247165
Record-Count: 355842

Data-File: 02-inventory_20230110-030000.tsv.gz
MD5-Digest: 8d1be438f98a172d0ff7e2d91ca7157e
File-Size: 85464370
Record-Count: 357974

Data-File: 03-inventory_20230110-030000.tsv.gz
MD5-Digest: c0b7a21a50a3cc43f32ad3d839cbb900
File-Size: 85037037
Record-Count: 354455

Data-File: 04-inventory_20230110-030000.tsv.gz
MD5-Digest: e5c8bc72108e1cb638dcdce080f32fa2
File-Size: 80764351
Record-Count: 339897
```

[image]

ExtractText is able to extract regex matches into dynamic groups successfully using below regex :
[image]

But the output is only the parent single flowfile carrying the first match (despite using 'use repeating capture group') carrying below attributes as expected:

```
Attribute ValuesShow modified attributes only
datafilename
01-inventory_20230110-040000.tsv.gz
No value set
datafilename.1
01-inventory_20230110-040000.tsv.gz
No value set
datafilename.2
02-inventory_20230110-040000.tsv.gz
No value set
datafilename.3
03-inventory_20230110-040000.tsv.gz
No value set
datafilename.3
04-inventory_20230110-040000.tsv.gz
No value set
```

How or what is the best way to dynamically split the flowfile into multiple copies based on the `datafile.x` attribute before sending to the downstream processors ? I see RouteOnText can do something similar but not sure if that would be efficient.

NOTE: The content of the original flowfile is not relevant as long as all unique `datafilename.X` can be extracted and used for the new flowfiles carrying existing attributes.

desired output:
`Incoming flowfile1 > ExtractText > flowfile1.1, flowfile1.2, flowfile1.3 (as many regex matches true)`

Comment: Check `ScriptedReader`, https://alasdairb.com/2021/09/21/getting-started-with-nifis-scriptedreader-by-processing-key-value-pairs-part-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way combining RouteText and SplitText. Its working but if anyone can suggest a better way please share.

[image]

Flowfile content:

```
Data-File: 01-inventory_20230110-060000.tsv.gz
Data-File: 02-inventory_20230110-060000.tsv.gz
Data-File: 03-inventory_20230110-060000.tsv.gz
Data-File: 04-inventory_20230110-060000.tsv.gz
Data-File: 05-inventory_20230110-060000.tsv.gz
Data-File: 06-inventory_20230110-060000.tsv.gz
Data-File: 07-inventory_20230110-060000.tsv.gz
Data-File: 08-inventory_20230110-060000.tsv.gz
```

[image]
[image]

Now each flowfile is only carrying a single row of Data-file entry which is sent to extractText which adds unique attribute `datafilename` for each matching regex of the original flowfile.

[image]